# How to use WhereBetween(time and date separate columns)?

Tags: laravel

I have table with for example 3 columns:

```
date1,time1,value
```

then I make a function:

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
  $start_date = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
  $end_date = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');
  if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
  {
    $dateScope = array($request->start_date, $request->end_date);
  } else {
    $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
  };
  $weather = chaira_weather::selectRaw('(date1+time1) as timestamp,value')
  ->whereBetween('timestamp', $dateScope)
  ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
  ->get();

  return response()->json($weather);

}
```

I have an error:

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "timestamp" does not exist
```

Any workaround?

**EDIT 2:**

CONCAT function gives me wrong date/time result: 10/12/201900:00:00. My way (date1+time1) as timestamp, works. havingBetween clause is not working again. But if i use only orderby the aliased timestamp is working.

I work in another approach:

```
  $weather = chaira_weather::selectRaw('(date1+time1) as timestamp,value')
  ->whereBetween('date1', $dateScope)
  ->whereBetween('time1', $dateScope)
  ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

Now it works. But again with problem. When the time1 is with same values. The query is giving me only one record per day. For example if date and time are between 01/12/2010 01:00:00 and 10/12/2010 01:00:00. The result is only in this hour 01:00:00:

```
01/12/2010 01:00:00,1
02/12/2010 01:00:00,3
03/12/2010 01:00:00,56
04/12/2010 01:00:00,7
05/12/2010 01:00:00,6
06/12/2010 01:00:00,8
07/12/2010 01:00:00,6
08/12/2010 01:00:00,7
09/12/2010 01:00:00,6
10/12/2010 01:00:00,32
```

If the time is not the same in query it works great. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
     $weather = DB::table('chaira_weather')
                    ->select('CONCAT(date1, time1) as timestamp, value')
                    ->whereBetween('timestamp', $dateScope)
                    ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also.

```
$weather = chaira_weather::select('CONCAT_WS(" ",date1,time1) as timestamp, value')
                ->whereBetween('timestamp', $dateScope)
                ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Edit 1:

```
$weather = chaira_weather::select('STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(" ",date1,time1),"%d,%m,%Y %H:%i:%s") as timestamp, value')
                ->whereBetween('timestamp', $dateScope)
                ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Edit 2 :

```
$weather = chaira_weather::select('value')
                ->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(" ",date1,time1),"%d,%m,%Y %H:%i:%s") >= ? AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(" ",date1,time1),"%d,%m,%Y %H:%i:%s") <= ?',array($startDate, $endDate))
                ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Just check your formats while comparing.

Comment: @HristianYordanov what is the error? Have added space in `CONCAT_WS`?

Comment: @HristianYordanov Check updated answer replace `single quote` with `double quote`.

Comment: @HristianYordanov Updated please check.

Comment: @zahid hasan emon said that  you can't use where clause on an aliased column

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `where` clause on an aliased column. you can `group`, `order` and use `having` on an aliased column only. so use `having` instead of `where`.

```
$weather = chaira_weather::selectRaw('CONCAT(date1,time1) as timestamp, value')
                ->havingBetween('timestamp', $dateScope)
                ->orderBy('timestamp', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Comment: CONCAT function gives me wrong date/time result: 10/12/201900:00:00. My way (date1+time1) as timestamp, works. havingBetween clause is not working again. But if i use only orderby the aliased timestamp is working.

Comment: just use a valid date format `(Y-m-d h:m:s)` and everything will work.

Comment: Yes I use valid but after concatination the date and time is next to each uder. @Prashant Deshmukh..... is more acurate. But still, please read my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think you chaira_weather model you can define scope and pass variable(date) to filter out your result

```
public function scopeStartDate($query, $start){
    return $query->where('start', '>=',Carbon::parse($start, 'Y-m-d'));
}

public function scopeEndDate($query, $end){
    return $query->where('end', '<=', Carbon::parse($end, 'Y-m-d'));
}
```

and then you can use like

```
chaira_weather::startDate($startDate)->endDate($endDate)->get();
```